# Running Selenium on jenkins takes my local chromedriver

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test our website with selenium via Jenkins so that everyday every feature gets tested.

The problem is that Jenkins fails because he is trying to get the chromedriver with my local path but there is no local path.

The error message:

> [ERROR] main(at.s2gplus.selenium.TestPromoteToAdmin)  Time elapsed:
> 0.006 s  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist:
> /opt/jenkins/workspace/buzzApi/C:/Users/mario/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe
> at
> at.s2gplus.selenium.TestPromoteToAdmin.main(TestPromoteToAdmin.java:36)

The code:

```
public class TestPromoteToAdmin {
    
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();


@Test
public void main() {


    
    driver.get("https://192.168.1.45:8080/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.id("details-button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("proceed-link")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("home-open-sign-in")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("tester");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("wurst01");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-action")).click();
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("left-menu-room-title-add-action"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("create-room-name-input")).sendKeys("Selenium Admin test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("create-room-description-input")).sendKeys("Selenium Test");
    driver.findElement(By.id("create-room-save")).click();
    
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement roomToClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Selenium Admin test')]")));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", roomToClick);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(roomToClick)).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'left-roomlist-settingsicon')]"))).click();
    WebElement addMemberBtn = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("room-settings-add-user")));
    addMemberBtn.click();
            
     
    WebElement checkBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("label[for='990bd6a8-62af-48c5-89a5-33019483c91f'")));//("cb732433-eae9-434b-96da-b4d5a499208c"));
    checkBox.click();
    WebElement addBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("room-settings-add-button"));
    addBtn.click();
    WebElement saveUserBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("room-settings-save"));
    saveUserBtn.click();
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'left-roomlist-settingsicon')]"))).click();
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("general-menu-list-item-settings"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("room-settings-context-change-role-to-moderator"))).click();
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("general-menu-list-item-settings"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("room-settings-context-change-role-to-admin"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("room-settings-save")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("top-logout")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("home-open-sign-in")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("tester01");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-password")).sendKeys("wurst02");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-action")).click();
    
    roomToClick = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Selenium Admin test')]")));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", roomToClick);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(roomToClick)).click();
    
    WebElement roomAdmin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Selenium Admin test')]"));
    String room = roomAdmin.getText();
    assertTrue(room, true);
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'left-roomlist-settingsicon')]"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("meeting-settings-open-close-room-modal"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("meeting-settings-close-room-confirm"))).click();

}

@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  
}       
@AfterTest
public void afterTest() {
    driver.quit();          
}       
}
```

line 36 is above `driver.get("https://192.168.1.45:8080/");` but I have deleted it a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Install Selenium Grid Plugin in the Jenkins, use below code for node setup. Update the versions of selenium server standalone jar and browser versions in the below code.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar - 
Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\yourpath\chromedriver.exe" -role node -hub 
http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=internet 
explorer,version=xx,platform=WINDOWS" -browser 
"browserName=chrome,version=xx,platform=WINDOWS"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update below line of code for starting

````
    
WebDriver driver = null;


@Test
public void main() {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\drivers\\ChromeDrivers\\85\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://192.168.1.45:8080/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); ```
````

Comment: Please create a driver folder in your framework and keep chrome driver and pass chromedriver in system property
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\drivers\\ChromeDrivers\\85\\chromedriver.exe");